# Google Pixel Digital Wellbeing - How does it measure the usage of the applications?

Tags: google-pixel, google-pixel-3-xl, digital-wellbeing

I noticed that many applications are logged as part of **today usage** in Digital Wellbeing dashboard app, even though I have never opened those app for today (for example).

I read [google documentation](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9346420?p=wellbeing_site&visit_id=637504389302044561-1193720974&rd=1#zippy=%2Cfind-out-how-much-time-you-spend-in-apps%2Climit-how-much-time-you-spend-in-an-app-each-day) and it doesn't really describe the details.

My concern is

- **Do those applications automatically running on background even though user doesn't use them?** (or)
- **It is because of how google measure the activity?**

Has anyone experience these before?

[image]

Comment: From my understanding the app measurement only considers if the app is in foreground and the screen is on. The main purpose seems to be to make it visible to you how many hours you spend using an app, so that it is detectable if you are addict to Facebook, Instagram, or a specific game.

Comment: @Robert, yes. That's how I understand. However I kept seeing apps which I didn't even open or use with very high usage hours. that's why I got confused and wondering daily usage dashboard statistics are incorrect or not.

Comment: Other apps you see may be those from which you got notifications-see this section [Find out how much time you spend in apps](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9346420?hl=en)